# Read from text file and put the comments in another file

Tags: c++

Design and program code that reads  C/C++ program file (Text file) and seperate the comments into another file?

I can read from text file but I'm not understanding how to separate comments into another file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 ifstream myReadFile;
 myReadFile.open("text.txt");
 char output[100];
 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
 while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


    myReadFile >> output;
    cout<<output;

 }
}
myReadFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this another assignment again?

Comment: I can read from text file but I'm not understanding how to separate comments into another file 


#include<iostream>

#include<fstream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

 ifstream myReadFile;

 myReadFile.open("text.txt");

 char output[100];
 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
 while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


    myReadFile >> output;

    cout<<output;


 }

}

myReadFile.close();

return 0;

}

Comment: If you have code relevant to your question, put it in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: `while ( !myReadFile.eof() )` is incorrect. read more about the "EOF anti-pattern" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941 and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Comment: A couple other suggestions: read the input file character-by-characters instead of token by token, and use a state machine to track whether or not you're currently 'in a comment'. The state that you're currently in will determine which file you should send output to.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: a finite state machine wouldn't be able to cut it. You need at least a counter to handle sequences like `/  \ newline \ newline \ newline \ newline * * /` (you cannot know when reading the first `/` if it's a start of a comment or not until you also read an arbitrary amount of line continuations).

Answer (score 0):

You first need to detect the comments. You would generally split the text and make it an array from there on, you will need to set a boolean as a place holder which will tell you when you encounter the closing tag of the comment.

Basically;

use http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/ as a reference and then scan the arrays one by one with the boolean. That way, you will know where the comment tag starts and ends,

```
boolean incomment =0 ;

while(incomment)
{
  // Construct your string.
}
```